# How can I access attributes from all parent classes?

Tags: python, function, overloading

```
class T(object):
    def f(self):
        pass

class T1(T):
    fields = set(('x1', 'y1', 'z1'))

class T2(T1):
    fields = set(('x2', 'y2'))

t=T2()
```

I want the call `t.f()` return `set(('x1','y1','z1','x2','y2'))` , and I don't want to rewrite 'f' in every child class, any idea?

Comment: You could have a list of `T`'s children, and create the set union of their `fields` attributes.

Comment: any other idea? I don't want to maintain a children list...thx

Comment: No. Each child can only access its own `fields` unless you have some other reference to their siblings.

Comment: The question itself could a bit more specific. Like: „How can I access attributes from all parent classes?“ or similar.

Comment: sorry, my English is a little pool~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your example:

```
class T(object):
    def f(self):
        fields = set()
        for cls in self.__class__.mro():
            if hasattr(cls, 'fields'):
                fields = fields.union(cls.fields)
        return fields

class T1(T):
    fields = set(('x1', 'y1', 'z1'))

class T2(T1):
    fields = set(('x2', 'y2'))

t = T2()
t.f()
```

returns:

```
{'x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2', 'z1'}
```

The method `mro()` gives you the method resolution order. This is a list of classes Python visits in turn to find a method. So, if a method does not exit in child class it will be looked for in the classes of this list. If the last class does not have this attribute it will throw an `AttributeError`. Here we use this  list to search for the attribute `fields` in the list of the parents and put all found sets in the resulting set `fields`.

Comment: Note that this will *only* traverse the MRO, so if you have e.g. `class T3(T1)` then `T3` and `T2` instances won't see each others' `fields`; I don't know whether that is a problem or a benefit for the OP!

Comment: yes, you are right. but this is the way I want. Because I have a Form that the ancestor has some field, different child has different field, and I don't want to rewrite the same method in the child class.